# How to get product detail from Product url key in magento?

Tags: magento

In Magento Backend, there is a URL Key field. Can anybody please show me way to find product detail from this field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "product detail" a product attribute or are you referring to the description?

Comment: Can you provide more info? What are you trying to do? Are you try to query this info using sql?

Comment: @PhilB : its product description.

Comment: @R.S : I just need to get product Description via Url Key field. It can be via query too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can get product details..by **loadByAttribute** function of class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('url_key', YOUR_URL_KEY_VALUE)
```